# Python. Looking for keywords within an entire website. Google API or beautifulsoup&similar?

Tags: python, google-api, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, keyword-search

I have a group of about 500 websites, and I would like to search them for some key phrase (from 5 to 10 phrases, I think) with the help of Python.

I have two solutions in mind:

1. Work with Beautifulsoup, and create a script that for every URL does two things: looking for each phrase within the text, look for the internal URLs, repeat the process for each of them and so on. Considering the fact that I am dealing with big websites, I am not sure that this solution can work.
2. Work with the Google API instead. I am resisting to this idea because I never worked with that API, and I have never seen this solution in other posts related with pictures here.

Which solution is better?

(I have just posted [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17475363/1014938) regarding the same amount of websites, but focused on picture scraping).

Comment: B.soup works as long as your need of the data scraping process is not in a "real time" fashion.